# Arithmetic operations inside templates

Tags: erb, puppet

I'm trying to add a number to a parameter inside a puppet template as below

```
"https://localhost:<%= 9443 + @offset %>/service/"
```

This gives me the following error.

Detail: String can't be coerced into Fixnum

'offset' is a numeric value. Is it possible to do this kind of arithmetic operations in puppet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything in puppet is parsed as a string. Give the following a try:

```
"https://localhost:<%= 9443 + @offset.to_i %>/service/"
```

or

```
"https://localhost:<%= 9443 + Integer(@offset) %>/service/"
```

Hope this helps.